# returning variable from custom table in WordPress (after retrieving from URL)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have code here which is supposed to grab the story id (SID) that is passed in the URL and ultimately reference the stories table to get the story_name for the SID and then print the story_name in the last line of the code. I am close. If I do var_dump() I get this message: 
string(7) “results”
I did try  but that returns nothing.

I am also wondering if I am even accessing the table correctly using $wpdb object if this table is not a table that begins with wp_ (that is to say, it is a custom table but it is in the same database).

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
// get the SID
$the_SID = ( isset( $_GET['SID'] ) ) ? $_GET['SID'] : false;

// get the story object (for story_name)
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT stories.story_name FROM stories where stories.SID =
$the_SID");
var_dump (results);
?>

Article Title: <b><?php echo $results->story_name ?></b>
```

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: I know it is. But I'm just trying to get this stuff to work before I can take the next step and worry about security. Just trying to get answers and learn the basics first. If you can provide a solution that is also sql injection safe, even better.

Comment: How would you rewrite this to be sql injection free Daniel?

Answer (score 0):

by default, every custom query returns an object so you need to access to the values by this way

```
echo $results->your_key;
```

Comment: Yes, I did try that first like <?php echo $results->story_name ?> and same issues. I think the problem is that I am using the $wpdb->get results and this is not a native wp table (although it is in the same database as the wp tables). But then again, I did get it to return string(7) “results” as I mentioned above, so maybe my approach is correct and I am just missing something.

Comment: Just for checking, is $the_SID getting a value? what happens if you change $the_SID by the number of any story post id?, if you test your query in mysql, it returns any result?

Comment: I was just looking into that Andres. While the URL does have the ID in it, it seems appears that SID is not being stored into the variable. I can't even get it to echo $the_SID; If I manually enter an ID, the code does display the corresponding story name, so something is faulty at $the_SID = ( isset( $_GET['SID'] ) ) ? $_GET['SID'] : false;

Comment: Ok, that is the problem, if you want, post the code you are using to set SID

Comment: GOT...embarrassing to admit problem. The variable name i was passing from the URL was not ID...it was article. Ugh. Sorry but thanks for your feedback. Now I can look into that sql injection prevention stuff someone mentioned on this post...